# Show that the weight of an object suspended from two other objects is equal to the sum of the vertical components of the two weights

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, weight

The following shows a mass with weight $M$ suspended from two other masses, labelled $m$

> [image]

The system is in equilibrium, and the question following from this diagram is to show that $M=2m\cos\theta$

My attempt was along the following lines:

We immediately know two things; we know that weight $M=m_1g$ where $m_1$ is the mass of the object, and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration constant, and we know that the tension from either of the top two strings will be the force they exert on point $A$, $\implies$ that each of these forces $= mg$, and since we are only interested in the vertical components, we specifically need $mg\cos\theta$

Now, given that the system is in equilibrium, we know that forces $\uparrow = $ forces $\downarrow$. $$\implies M=2mg\cos\theta$$ $$m_1g=2mg\cos\theta$$ and here is where my issue lies, I know that to get the RHS to the form $2m\cos\theta$ I need to divide through by the GA constant, but that would also affect the LHS. Is my logic so far correct? Or is there a completely different way in which I can show that this equation is true for this diagram?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: -1 for the incomprehensible title.

Comment: It seems to me that you answer your own question in your last equation.  Can you clarify what is confusing you?

Comment: I've misinterpreted the question, as pointed out to me by Steeven in his answer @garyp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply misread a detail in the question.

$M$ is not weight. It is mass. So you cannot do $M=m_1g$.

You are actually almost done in the first step of the derivation, if you just fix the LHS so that $M$ is a mass instead of a weight.